# Goole sheet Vlookup with name rang

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with a lot of Named reges.
I would like to enter the named range in culm AH1 and make a lookup in AH2

This one works =VLOOKUP(AG2,Filter_By_Year,4,)
this one doesn't =VLOOKUP(AG2,AH1,4,)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

As you're currently referencing AH1, Google Sheets is seeing the value there simply as a string, not a range. You need to let Sheets know that you intend to reference the *range* with that name, not the literal string:

`=VLOOKUP(AG2,INDIRECT(AH1),4,)`